# Running a Grunt Task directly from Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

How do I execute a Grunt task directly from Node without shelling out to the CLI?

I've got the following "POC" code; however, "stuff" is never logged.

```
var grunt = require('grunt');

grunt.registerTask('default', 'Log some stuff.', function() {
    console.log('stuff');
});

grunt.task.run('default'); // This is probably not the right command
```

I'm pretty new to Grunt, so I'm probably missing something obvious.  I suspect the command I'm using to "run" the task is just queuing it, and doesn't actually start running things.  I can't find documentation for manually running things, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Update

While this is the answer, Grunt has tons of issues with being run directly from Node.  Not the least of which is when the grunt task fails, it calls `process.exit` and nicely quits your node instance.  I cannot recommend trying to get this to work.

---

Ok, I'll just answer my own question.  I was right, the command I had was wrong.

Updated code:

```
var grunt = require('grunt');

grunt.registerTask('default', 'Log some stuff.', function() {
    console.log('stuff');
});

grunt.tasks(['default']);
```

Comment: How do we add options for this task?

Comment: there is already new API and you need to run `grunt.task.run(['default'])` instead

Answer (score 4):

it take much time and finally, I already made it working for me

```
   var util = require('util')
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    var child = exec("/usr/local/bin/grunt --gruntfile /path/to/Gruntfile.js", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
      util.print('stdout: ' + stdout);
      util.print('stderr: ' + stderr);
      if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you do the following?

```
grunt.tasks("default");
```

I've created an Grunt runner in one of my projects that does some parsing and then call the line above. Almostly what you already answered, but with support for a `Gruntfile.js`.

Comment: watch out though, this kills the process you run it in.

Comment: anyway to avoid that?

Answer (score -1):

We're using Jenkins for our builds.  So here is how we resolved the issue using bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
grunt full-build | tee /dev/stderr | awk '/Aborted/ || /Fatal/{exit 1}'
echo rv: $?
exit $?
```

The use of /dev/stderr is because we're running within Jenkins and we still want to ouput to show up within the console.

Visualjeff